# Import StartMenu.xml onto existing users profile

Tags: xml, batch-file, import, startmenu

I have designed a startmenu layout that I wish to apply to another machine. I have exported the xml file through the following command:

```
export-startlayout –path C:\layout.xml
```

However, simply switching "export" with "import" doesn't seem to work when trying to apply the layout to a newly created user profile. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What does this have to do with batch files? `export-startlayout` is a PowerShell command.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, should have mentioned I'm trying to automate this, so I can compile the code into a batch to execute it.